# Setting std=c99 flag in GCC

Tags: c, programming-languages, c99

I was wondering if there were any files in which I could set the `-std=c99` flag, so that I would not have to set it for every compilation. I am using GCC 4.4 on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Instead of calling `/usr/bin/gcc`, use `/usr/bin/c99`. This is the Single-Unix-approved way of invoking a C99 compiler. On an Ubuntu system, this points to a script which invokes `gcc` after having added the `-std=c99` flag, which is precisely what you want.

Comment: Ok I am new to programming on linux (learning at college), how do I use /usr/bin/c99 ? I am using Vim-Gnome with C plugin in which I just do \rr to compile and run.

Comment: From what I find on the Web, there is a global variable called `C_CCompiler` which designates the C compiler. It is normally set to `gcc`. Replace its contents with `c99` and things should go fine. See the help file on: http://lug.fh-swf.de/vim/vim-doc/csupport.html

Comment: Note that using c99 on Mac may give you surprising results: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182413

Answer (score 19):

How about `alias gcc99= gcc -std=c99`?

Comment: +1 That's what I do. And while you are at it add the -Wall and -pedantic flags to the alias.

Comment: +1. Now that's what my alias actually looks like: `alias gcc99=gcc -Wall -pedantic -ansi -std=c99`. Yes, with `ansi` as well.

Comment: @dirkgently: so what standard (if any) is GCC implementing with `-std=c99 -ansi`? You've enabled C99, and then disabled anything not in C89, does that result in the common subset of both?

Comment: @Steve Jessop: GCC manual -- `This turns off certain features of GCC that are incompatible with ISO C90(when compiling C code), or of standard C++ (when compiling C++ code), such as the asm and typeof keywords, and predefined macros such as unix and vax that identify the type of system you are using. It also enables the undesirable and rarely used ISO trigraph feature. For the C compiler, it disables recognition of C++ style `//' comments as well as the inline keyword. ` Reading that section may be helpful: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#C-Dialect-Options

Comment: I did read that, but it tells me what GCC does, not why it's useful ;-). In particular, how and why is `-ansi -std=c99  -pedantic` better than `-std=c89 -pedantic`?

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Maximize portability, minimize vendor implementations. Also, don't much like `alloca` kind of functions. So on ...

Comment: Ah, no, I see what I misunderstood now. The -std=c99 overrides the -std=c89, because it occurs after it in the arguments. Or maybe only mostly overrides it. Is alloca disabled by `-ansi -std=c99`, but not by `-std=c99` alone?

Comment: @Steve Jessop: The order of arguments _does not_ matter. The combination does.

Comment: The order certainly does matter. For example `int main() { // thing <newline> }`, where <newline> is a newline. Compiles with `gcc -ansi -std=c99 -pedantic`, but not with `gcc -std=c99 -ansi -pedantic`.

Comment: Sorry, yes the order matters when they are of the same type. I stand corrected. http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html para#6

Comment: I'd add `-Wmissing-prototypes` and `-Wstrict-prototypes` (and maybe `-Wextra`).  If I am confident the code will support it, I'd use `-Werror` too, for good measure; that treats any warnings as fatal errors.  It is great discipline; it can be harsh, too.

Answer (score 1):

```
export CFLAGS="-std=c99"
export CC="gcc"

make
```

Some distributions and in most UNIX based OS's have aliases or wrappers for this stuff.