# What is the difference between `cc -std=c99` and `c99` on Mac OS?

Tags: c, xcode, compiler-construction, c99

Given the following program:

```
/*  Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000. */

#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long int method_one(const unsigned long int n);

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        unsigned long int sum = method_one(1000000000);
        if (sum != 0) {
                printf("Sum: %lu\n", sum);
        } else {
                printf("Error: Unsigned Integer Wrapping.\n");
        }

        return 0;
}

unsigned long int
method_one(const unsigned long int n)
{
        unsigned long int i;
        unsigned long int sum = 0;
        for (i=1; i!=n; ++i) {
                if (!(i % 3) || !(i % 5)) {
                        unsigned long int tmp_sum = sum;
                        sum += i;
                        if (sum < tmp_sum)
                                return 0;
                }
        }

        return sum;
}
```

On a Mac OS system (Xcode 3.2.3) if I use `cc` for compilation using the `-std=c99` flag everything seems just right:

```
nietzsche:problem_1 robert$ cc -std=c99 problem_1.c -o problem_1
nietzsche:problem_1 robert$ ./problem_1 
Sum: 233333333166666668
```

However, if I use `c99` to compile it this is what happens:

```
nietzsche:problem_1 robert$ c99 problem_1.c -o problem_1
nietzsche:problem_1 robert$ ./problem_1 
Error: Unsigned Integer Wrapping.
```

Can you please explain this behavior?

Comment: Can't use use 1000000 as the example which shows the difference and faster to compute? ;)

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code compiled with both compilers?  I imagine that `unsigned long int` is 32-bits in one of the compilers and 64-bits in the other.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`c99` is a wrapper of `gcc`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/c99.1.html). It exists because POSIX requires it. `c99` will generate a 32-bit (i386) binary by default.

[`cc` is a symlink to `gcc`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/cc.1.html), so it takes whatever default configuration `gcc` has. `gcc` produces a binary in native architecture by default, which is x86_64.

`unsigned long` is 32-bit long on i386 on OS X, and 64-bit long on x86_64. Therefore, `c99` will have a "Unsigned Integer Wrapping", which `cc -std=c99` does not.

You could force `c99` to generate a 64-bit binary on OS X by the `-W 64` flag.

```
c99 -W 64 proble1.c -o problem_1
```

(Note: by `gcc` I mean the actual gcc binary like `i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1`.)

Comment: Wow, what an incredibly stupid setup. Is there any reason for this madness?

Comment: @R..: I don't know. Maybe only Apple knows.

Answer (score 5):

Under Mac OS X, cc is symlink to gcc (defaults to 64 bit), and c99 is not (defaults to 32bit).

/usr/bin/cc -> gcc-4.2

And they use different default byte-sizes for data types.

```
/** sizeof.c
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv)
{
   printf("sizeof(unsigned long int)==%d\n", (int)sizeof(unsigned long int));

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

cc -std=c99 sizeof.c
./a.out
sizeof(unsigned long int)==8


c99 sizeof.c
./a.out
sizeof(unsigned long int)==4
```

Quite simply, you are overflowing (aka wrapping) your integer variable when using the c99 compiler.

.PMCD.