# Scanf array limit in C?

Tags: c, arrays, scanf, variable-length-array

I have some little error in C:

> **Error: expression must have a constant value**

I know, that's mean that my limit must have a constant value, but how i can to solve that when i have this situation?

```
printf("Type limit: ");
scanf("%i",&limit);
int arr[limit];
```

Thanks.

**EDIT**:

Ok guys, another problem, sorry if i spam.

```
    int num,limit,i;
    printf("Type limit: ");
    scanf("%i",&limit);
    int *arr = (int*)malloc(limit*sizeof(int));
    for(i=0;i<limit;i++)
    {
        printf("Type num %i: ",i);
        arr[i] = scanf("%i",&num);
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
```

> error 4 error c2109 subscript requires array or pointer type

Comment: You need to use `malloc` since `limit` is not known at compile time (or go into [VLA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) territory).

Comment: Compile as C99 or C2011. Variable length arrays were not in C89.

Comment: Don't post an edit of your question as an answer next time, just use edit feature. Check my answer now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `malloc`:

```
printf("Type limit: ");
scanf("%i",&limit);
int *arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * limit);
```

Comment: Thank's

I use this and works:
int *arr = (int*)malloc(limit*sizeof(int));

Thank's. Problem solved.

Comment: I agree with @qPCR4vir . Also, you should remove the type casting before the `malloc`. It is not good practice...

Comment: @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira
If i remove cast, then i have error.

Comment: @user1814358 interesting... you should have a warning, not an error... post your code, please, there might be something else wrong...

Comment: @user1814358: Are you compiling this code as C or C++?  C++ requires that you cast the result of `malloc`, C does not.  This may also explain why you couldn't use the VLA in your original post.

Answer (score 4):

Variable-length arrays with automatic storage duration are allowed since C99. In C89, it is not possible to allocate an array with automatic storage duration, size of which is not known at the compile time. Use [`malloc`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) to allocate it dynamically:

```
printf("Type limit: ");
scanf("%i", &limit);

int* arr = malloc(limit * sizeof(int));
```

and don't forget to call [`free(arr)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/free) to deallocate this memory  once you don't need it anymore.

---

To your question about initializing this array with values being read from stdin in a loop:

```
for(i = 0; i < limit; ++i)
    arr[i] = scanf("%i", &num);
```

reads each value, stores it into `num` variable and then `1` is assigned into `arr[i]` since [`scanf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) returns *"number of input items successfully matched and assigned"* (which is 1 in this case). You can read into array elements directly:

```
for(i = 0; i < limit; ++i)
    scanf("%i", &arr[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

C89 and earlier versions of C didin't support run-time sizing of arrays. You need to turn on C99 (or newer) support in your compiler.

If you are using Linux you can either type:

```
gcc -std=c99
```

or

```
c99
```

to compile code written for c99.

[Setting std=c99 flag in GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193634/setting-std-c99-flag-in-gcc)

Answer (score 0):

```
int *arr=malloc( limit*sizeof(int) );
```

This will allocated sufficient memory in the heap for your array of `limit` `int`’s.
But this array will be “dynamical” (the size is set at run-time), and it will be your responsibility to “`free`” this memory  when you not longer need it. Your variable arr will be just a pointer to that memory.
`int arr1[10];` on the other hand separate a memory space for 10 `int` in the stack, and your variable `arr1` is that memory. The compiler need to know the size. If you past it to a function taking `int*` it will “decay" to `int*,` that is, a pointer to the first element `arr1[0].`

Comment: @user1814358 :  Are you sure it is the code with the error, or that was with int arr=(int)malloc....?