# New to Dynamically memory "first time"

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

why the error

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int *p, size, i;
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("input.txt","r");
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &size);

    p = (int*)malloc(size*sizeof(int));  //error
    for (i = 0; i <size; i++)
        fscanf(fp, "%d", &p[i]);

    for (i = size-1; i>= 0; i--)
        printf("%d\n", p[i]);

    free(p);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

i'm using "Geany" on ubuntu

and on Geany compiler :

fileName.c:11:2: warning implicit declaration of function 'malloc' [-Wimplicit-function-declatation]
fileName.c:11:12: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'malloc' [enabled by default]
fileName.c:18:12: warning: implicit declaration of function 'free' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
fileName.c:18:12: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'free' [enabled-by default]
compilation finished successfully

Comment: Stop casting the return value of malloc.  If you stop doing that this would be an error as it should be instead of a warning.  You do not need to (nor should you) cast to or from a `void*` in C.  The conversion is safe and implicit.

Comment: @Mahesh: They should be errors and, in C99, they would be errors.

Comment: @EdS. By the time I realized and deleted, you commented :)

Comment: @EdS. - gcc/clang will still only warn in C99 mode for implicit declarations, unless you supply `-pedantic-errors`

Comment: Thanks you all, how can i compiling from the terminal on Ubuntu

Comment: @Alamin - `gcc -o foo foo.c -Wall`

Comment: @teppic Thanks, but what `c99 -W 64 proble1.c -o problem_1` from [link](http://http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193634/setting-std-c99-flag-in-gcc)

Comment: @Alamin, using c99 instead of gcc is fine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing the following header include:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

The prototypes for `malloc` and `free` are defined in the `stdlib.h` header file which you missed out.

If you're unsure which header files to include for some standard C functions, you could always use `man` to figure it out.

For this case [`man malloc`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) would have shown the required header file to be included.

BTW, in your code you're not checking if `fp` is `NULL` after `fopen`.

`fopen` can and will fail if the file does not exist or you do not have permissions to open the file (for reading in your case).

```
fp = fopen("input.txt","r");
if (fp == NULL)
{
    printf("Error opening input.txt\n");
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: but in Terminal it say:Segmentation fault (core dumped)


------------------
(program exited with code: 139)
Press return to continue

Comment: is that because i'm working on ubuntu

Comment: @Alamin - I've updated the answer with a probable reason for the segmentation fault. You should be checking the value of `fp` after `fopen` to make sure it is not `NULL`. Otherwise fscanf tries to read from a `NULL` file pointer.

Comment: Thanks alot for your informative reply

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
warning implicit declaration of function 'xxxxxx' [-Wimplicit-function-declatation]
```

Always means the same thing. The compiler can't find the function you're talking about. Most of the time that's because you forgot the correct header file.

If you type `man <function name>`, in this case `man malloc` into your terminal (or google) you'll get a page telling you what header files you need. In this case `<stdlib.h>`, include it and the warning will go away.

Comment: Thanks alot for your informative reply