# Forcing compiler to C99 standard

Tags: c, gcc, clang, c99, c11

I was coding on my project when I discovered that the anonymous structs I've been using for a while are actually only available in C11, not C99, the standard I want to code against.

Given the following code:

```
struct data {
    int a;
    struct {
        int b;
        int c;
    };
};

int main()
{
    struct data d;

    d.a = 0;
    d.b = 1;
    d.c = 2;
    return 0;
}
```

This code should only compile in C11 (or if compiler extensions provide this feature and are enabled). So let's see the results on different compilers:

#### clang 5

```
compiler:
    Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
    Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0
    Thread model: posix
command: 
    clang -std=c99 -Wall test.c -o test
result: 
    **OK**
```

#### gcc 4.1

```
compiler:
    gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)
command: 
    gcc -std=c99 -Wall test.c -o test
result: 
    **NOT OK**
    test.c:6: warning: declaration does not declare anything
    test.c: In function 'main':
    test.c:14: error: 'struct data' has no member named 'b'
    test.c:15: error: 'struct data' has no member named 'c'
```

#### gcc 4.7

```
compiler:
    gcc (GCC) 4.7.2 20121109 (Red Hat 4.7.2-8)
command: 
    gcc -std=c99 -Wall test.c -o test
result: 
    **OK**
    test.c: In function 'main':
    test.c:11:14: warning: variable 'd' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
```

I've always tried to force the compiler to C99 mode by specifying `-std=c99`, but obviously this doesn't work (except for gcc 4.1 which compiles fine without the -std parameter). 
So my question is now, how can I force the compilers gcc and clang, in any version, to issue an error if I write code that does not conform to the standard I specify using `-std`? Is there some command line argument that I don't know of?

Comment: Does this SO thread provide anything to you?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193634/setting-std-c99-flag-in-gcc

Comment: @miushock thanks, but no, that doesn't help either. using `c99` instead of `gcc` still compiles where it should fail...

Comment: I believe the `-pedantic` flag _might_ be needed to warn on language extensions (GNU C has anon structs in C99). Maybe this answer regarding [/usr/bin/c99](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2193730/3080396) is useful to you.

Comment: @MBlanc that's it! Using `-pedantic` I get a warning that I use non C99 features. Since it's a warning it still compiles, but that's better than nothing (wished I'd be an error). Post this comment again as an answer and I'm happy to accept it! Thanks!

Comment: @grasbueschel You can add the [`-Werror`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) flag to turn (all) warnings into errors

Comment: @Kninnug great! will do so...thanks!

Comment: The usual recommendation to get `gcc` to behave standardly is `-Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -pedantic`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`-std=c99` won't disable language extensions  (GNU C has anon structs in C99).

The [`-pedantic`](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#cmdoption-pedantic) (or [`-pedantic-errors`](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#cmdoption-pedantic-errors)) flags make the compiler warn on language extensions.

Answer (score 10):

Both `gcc` and `clang` allow a [large number of extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html#C-Extensions) and [here for clang](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#extensions-supported-by-clang). `clang` in general attempts to support most of the extensions that `gcc` does. Both will even allow you to use features that are *C* only in *C++* for example [VLAs which are a C99 feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21273829/does-int-size-10-yield-a-constant-expression/21273849#21273849).

In this case both are allowing you to use [Unnamed struct/union fields within structs/unions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Unnamed-Fields.html) in *C99* mode even though it is a *C11* feature.

The [Language Standards Supported by GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html#Standards) documents well what flags are required to turn these into warnings and errors and as far as I know `clang` follows the same conventions:

> [...]to obtain all the diagnostics required by the standard, you should also specify -pedantic (or -pedantic-errors if you want them to be errors rather than warnings). [...]

So `-pedantic` will warn you if you are using an extension and `-pedantic-errors` will turn these warnings into an error. With `-pedantic` flag you should see a warning like this in `gcc`:

> warning: ISO C99 doesn't support unnamed structs/unions [-Wpedantic]

and this in `clang` (*[see it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/45660298c06296ee)*):

> warning: anonymous structs are a C11 extension [-Wc11-extensions]

and it turn into an error with `-pedantic-errors`.