# Why isn't GCC's acceptance of void-pointer arithmetic considered a bug?

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, ansi-c

There are at least three different posts about how void pointer arithmetic is prohibited in C; that gcc 4.8.2 allows it, assuming that a void is of byte size; and how one can turn on extra pedantic warnings to trigger an error. Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* compile gcc -Wall -o try try.c */

int main() {
  char *str="string";
  void *vp= (void *) str;

  ++vp; /* arithmetic on void point.  huh? */

  printf("%s\n", (char*)vp);
  return 0;
}
```

My question is about thinking about what a C compiler is supposed to do in case of invalid code.  Is it not considered a bug when a compiler does not issue a compile error on invalid code?

And this seems like bizarre behavior for a compiler, anyway — even if gcc does not issue a compile error, at the very least, it could issue a "deprecated" warning with the default compiler flags.  And, even with
`-Wall`, it is still not even giving a warning.  Huh?  It surprised me because gcc seems very mature otherwise and C is not exactly a novel or complex language.

Comment: Did you try `-pedantic`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13113325/391161

Comment: Both `gcc` and `clang` [warn when you are using extensions by using the -pedantic flag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22285043/forcing-compiler-to-c99-standard/22285657#22285657) and you can use the `-pedantic-errors` flag to turn them into errors.

Comment: Mainly because GCC developers consider it a feature that is beneficial.

Comment: guys, this is *not* the same question.  and whoever gave it a '-1', did not read my question.  I stated upfront that the void* question was answered.  the question was whether this makes gcc a non-compliant compiler in its default configuration.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The C standard makes an attempt to perform pointer arithmetic on `void*` a *constraint violation*, which means that any conforming C compiler must issue at least one diagnostic message for any program containing such an attempt. The warning may be a non-fatal error; in that case, the compiler may then go on to generate code whose behavior is defined by the implementation.

gcc, by default, does not warn about pointer arithmetic on `void*`. This means that gcc, by default, *is not a conforming C compiler*.

One could argue that this is a bug, but in its default mode gcc is not a compiler for standard C but for GNU C. (A Fortran compiler's failure to be a conforming C compiler is also not a bug.)

Carefully chosen command-line options can force gcc to at least attempt to be conforming. For example:

```
gcc -std=cXX -pedantic
```

where `XX` is one of `90`, `99`, or `11`, will cause gcc to warn about pointer arithmetic on `void*`. Replacing `-pedantic` with `-pedantic-errors` causes it to treat such arithmetic as a fatal error.

Comment: 2 cents: Key take-away from this post is: GCC doesn't compile standard C, by default.  For portability, I like to use **-ansi -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror** and then loosen it up if I need features/behaviour not present in C89 and if GCC gives me grief about something which ought to be fine by C89 and which is intentional.

Answer (score 2):

Sure *invalid* standard C code could be legal in a specific compiler, it's called **compiler extension**.

It's true in this case, from https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html

> In GNU C, addition and subtraction operations are supported on pointers to void and on pointers to functions. This is done by treating the size of a void or of a function as 1.

If you need your code to be portable, it's always a good idea to stick with standard C, but if your code runs only on a specific platform, it's no harm to use certain compiler extensions.

Comment: Extensions are permitted, but a conforming compiler still must issue diagnostic when required. Pointer arithmetic on `void*` requires a diagnostic.

Answer (score 0):

C11 standard n1570 S6.5.6/2:

> For addition, either both operands shall have arithmetic type, or one operand shall be a
>   pointer to a complete object type and the other shall have integer type. (Incrementing is
>   equivalent to adding 1.)

The language for C++ is similar.

It's definitely not standards-conforming behaviour. I think the GCC team already know that.

The answer is that a compliant compiler should issue a diagnostic, and then generate whatever code it likes (or not).