# Not getting debugging symbols to be generated

Tags: gcc, makefile, gdb

I am using make and debugging symbols are not getting generated. Here is my makefile:

```
program: ui.o data.o string.o
        c99 -ggdb -o program2 ui.o data.o string.o

clean :
        rm -f program2

ui.o : ui.c data.h
        c99 -ggdb -c ui.c

data.o : data.c data.h
        c99 -ggdb -c data.c

string.o : string.c string.h
        c99 -ggdb -c string.c
```

How can I generate debugging symbols? When I run gdb using `gdb program2` it gives the warning "No debugging symbols found".

Comment: Is `c99` a valid call to the compiler ? I think you should call it like this instead (and keep the other flags) : `gcc -std=c99`

Comment: It generates the executable. I was told that running c99 is the normal way to compile c99 code using gcc, according to Thomas Pornin's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193634/setting-std-c99-flag-in-gcc

Comment: Okay thanks I didn't know that. I guess I'm using a too old version of gcc. Well since it's not the problem I can't help you more, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your `Makefile` builds `program2`, but pretends to build `program` (i.e. the target on the first line is wrong).
2. Your `clean` target should also clean `*.o`, otherwise `make clean; make` will only *relink* `program`, but will not *recompile* any objects in it.

One of the above factors is a likely explanation for missing debug symbols you've observed.